# Are Sequelize.js model queries the same for mySQL as they are for PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have worked with Sequelize and PostgreSQL before, but not with mySQL. Do I query Sequelize models the same way for mySQL as I would with PostgreSQL?

For example, will this Sequelize query do the same thing in mySQL as it would for PostgreSQL?

```
const order = await Order.findOne({
  where: {
    userId: req.user.id,
    status: 'in-progress'
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: LineItem,
      include: [{model: Item}]
    }
  ]
})
```

A simpler (completely different and unrelated!) query from sequelize-guides.netlify.com :

```
const sevenYearOldPugs = await Pug.findAll({
  where: { // like saying: SELECT * from pugs WHERE age = 7;
    age: 7,
  }
})
```

Comment: There are some differences that you can find in the documentation, but for your examples, yes it will work the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Some special properties don't work for all DBMS (e.g. `returning` and `searchPath` are PostgreSQL only), mostly because that feature is DBMS specific (not a part of the SQL standard), but you can find those in the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll).

Additionally some datatypes are treated differently, you can find that information [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/data-types.html). You'll notice that a lot of them are PostgreSQL only, so be careful if you're reusing some model definitions from a PostgreSQL project.

Comment: Great! Perfect @5ar was Sequelize created for PostgreSQL first?

Comment: As far as I know, no, it was always an ORM intended to be used for multiple RDBMS. I think that the reason for a lot of PostgreSQL only features is PostgreSQL's popularity which in turn probably resulted in a lot of contributions for PostgreSQL features on Sequelize)